# On click on a button,I want to redirect to the page from which a record is selected in jqgrid

Tags: mvcjqgrid

Opened a record which is in 10th page in jqgrid,once the record is edited and saved..we need to display a button where it redirects to the page from which the record is opened from the jqgrid

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is clear. Can you please explain more detailed. Where you need to display the button? From where you open the record and etc. Any details are important.

Comment: I have an episode list page, where episodes are displayed in the jqgrid,I tried to open an episode from the 10th page of the jqgrid,on click on the episode,edit episode page is opened.in the edit episode page I need to place a back button,on click on that back button,it should be redirected to episode list page and the jqgrid should display the 10thpage.. application is a static one

Comment: You can open your editing episode page as modal. In this case after editing you will just to close the modal and you will stay in page 10 of the grid.